# $\sigma(\xi)$ is independent of a fixed $\sigma$-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, independence

I want to prove that if $\lim_{n->\infty}\xi_n = \xi$ pointwise and each $\xi_n$ is independent from a fixed sigma-algebra $F$ then $\xi$ is independent from $F$.

I understand that $\sigma(\xi)$ will be independent from $F$ too.

How can it be proved: if $\sigma(\xi)$ is independent from $F$ then $\xi$ is independent of $F$?

Comment: How do you define the independence of random variables? Doesn't the definition itself say it happens when their sigma-algebras are independent? So what you're asking for follows from definition, really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\sigma (\xi)=\{\xi^{-1} (A): A \in \mathcal B\}$ where $\mathcal B$ is the Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R$. The  hypothesis gives  $P(\xi ^{-1}(A) \cap E)=P(\xi ^{-1}(A) )P(E)$  for any Borel set $A$ and any $E \in F$. This is the definition of $\xi$ being independent of $F$.